# How to load all functions of my Fortran DLL to my C++/QT 5 project?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, linker, fortran

I'm developing a **cross-platform** x64 (Windows/Linux) software using **C++/QT 5** to create a GUI interface (with QT Creator IDE) and **Fortran 2003** to deal with all math calculation part.

My problem related with how QT loads static (*.lib or *.a files) and dynamic libraries (*.dll or *.so files) and what is the "best way" to do this.

**Fortran Static Lib + QT Static Linking:**

At this moment, I **only** get all working perfectly when I choose to generate a Fortran Static Lib and then link it **statically** with my QT Project adding this line in the QT project file (*.pro).

```
LIBS += "full_path_to_my_lib.lib".
```

In this static linking case, I created a C++ header (*.h) to create the functions reference of my Fortran Lib. This header file contains:

```
extern "C" {
    void sum(int *a, int *b, int* c);
    void sub(int *a, int *b, int* c);
}
```

My Fortran file is like this:

```
! My sum subrotine:
subroutine sum(a, b, c) BIND(C,name = 'sum')
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::sum
    use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
    implicit none

    integer (C_INT), intent(in)  :: a, b
    integer (C_INT), intent(out) :: c

    c = a + b
end subroutine sum

! My subtractive subrotine:   
subroutine sub(a, b, c) BIND(C,name = 'sub')
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::sub
    use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
    implicit none

    integer (C_INT), intent(in)  :: a, b
    integer (C_INT), intent(out) :: c

    c = a - b
end subroutine sub
```

**Until this point: All working ok!**

**PROBLEM: Fortran Dynamic Lib + QT Dynamic Linking:**

Reading about how QT can load dynamically all the functions that are inside a generic DLL, I'm confuse about the difference of this 2 QT classes:

1- QPluginLoader: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpluginloader.html

2- QLibrary: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html

I would like to know which one I should to choose to my project.
My final goal is: I have a "main application" and this application can be expanded with new future developed plugins.
This new plugins will be developed in a 2 steps:

a) The user interface will be made using C++ and QT

b) All math and calculations will be made using Fortran

So, I think that a new future developed plugin should be a **one single DLL file** that contains all C++/QT graphical user interface and all Fortran math calculations inside the same DLL file. Right?

So, if the future plugin installer puts this **single DLL file** inside a pre-defined Main Application "plugins folder"...the main application will find this new plugin and load it automatically.

Am'I right?

If yes, could you please give a C++/QT example that loads a "generic" DLL file (like my Fortran DLL example above) and how to load **all internal DLL functions in run-time**.

Finally I saw in QT 5.13 examples 2 QT projects that is very close with my needs:

a) Plug & Paint Example (This is the "Main Application")

Link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-app-example.html

b) Plug & Paint Basic Tools Example (This is the plugin that loads in "run-time")

Link: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-plugins-basictools-example.html

My problem with this QT example is that the "plugin part" is that:

a) The C++ code **is not** a simple DLL like my Fortran example above and it have other **QT classes dependecies that are needed** to create a valid QT plugin.

b) The plugin project **output file is a *.lib (static library file)**. Why? I my mind was thinking that this should be a *.dll (dynamic library file).

Well, looking in the "main application" example source code, I think that it loads this *.lib file at run-time using QPluginLoader. **Does it make any sense?**

Until now, I was thinking that:

a) *.lib or *.a => **Static Linking at compile time**

b) *.dll or *.so => **Dynamic Linking at run-time**

In what I'm wrong? And **how can I load dynamically *.dll files in my QT project?**

### GOOD NEWS:

I got this code working well. It calls the "sub" function that is inside my DLL file.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
int c = 0;

QLibrary myLib("Dll1.dll");
typedef void (*MyPrototype)(int*, int*, int*);
MyPrototype sub = (MyPrototype) myLib.resolve("sub");
if (sub) {
    sub(&a, &b, &c);
}

qDebug() << "C = " << c; // Output: c = 2
```

**Question 1:**
In the line:

```
MyPrototype sub = (MyPrototype) myLib.resolve("sub");
```

I got this warning:

```
Use of old-style cast
```

How to do a "new-style cast" and remove this warning?

**Question 2:**
What is `MyPrototype` in this code? **Why it works?**

**Question 3:**
Can I put QT GUI elements (Window, buttons, labels, etc...) **inside a DLL file?**

Comment: *If yes, could you please give a C++/QT example that loads a "generic" DLL file (like my Fortran DLL example above) and how to load all internal DLL functions in run-time.* -- A DLL can be loaded manually without any .lib files or import libraries by calling `LoadLibrary` and then `GetProcAddress` to retrieve pointers to the DLL functions.

Comment: I think that `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` will work **only in Windows environment.**

I think that QT5 can do this in a **cross-plataform way (Windows/Linux/Mac)**.

Of course, I have to give 3 DLL plataform files: *.dll (Windows), *.so (Linux) and *.dylib (Mac)...no problems here...
Right?

Comment: You can use [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html) to do the cross-platform loading of the DLL's.

Comment: I think you should leave this to compiler or link flag, not mess it within your code. If you ever use gfortran in linux, you will notice in /usr/lib[64], there are both libgfortran.a and libgfortran.so for static and dynamic link purpose. By default gcc will try to link dynamic library first, but you can force it link the static one with gcc flag -Wl,-Bstatic before the library, of cause the dynamic library must in the search path. I have no experience with window, I guess it works similarly.